# uwsgi .ini param equivalents in nginx (500 errors on flask app)

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have been attempting to move my flask code into uwsgi with nginx. It's gone through 502 (wrong socket filename) to 404 (default app 0 - not loading runable code in nginx config), to now a 500, and I have no info on why.

- A) should uwsgi params be in nginx or uwsgi?
- B) app name seems so picky all the time. is it just me?

Slowly but surely the modifications seem to be coming from problems in my uwsgi.ini or nginx.sites files, and I really just want someone to vet them and explain what's happening.

uwsgi.ini:

```
# can't these take over from nginx?
[uwsgi]
base = /home/aristatek/britishQueue
home = /home/aristatek/britishQueue
venv = /home/aristatek/britishQueue/clearable
socket = /home/aristatek/britishQueue/uwsgi.sock
chmod-socket = 666
wsgi-file = uwsgi.py
callable = application
daemonize=/home/aristatek/britishQueue/uwsgi.log
master = true
processes = 4
threads = 2
```

nginx config:

```
server {
    server_name intern.alpha.aristatek.com default_server;
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root /home/aristatek/britishQueue/srv/;
    }
    location /api/ { try_files $uri @britishQueue; }
    location @britishQueue {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_BASE /home/aristatek/britishQueue;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_HOME /home/aristatek/britishQueue;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_VENV /home/aristatek/britishQueue/clearable;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_MODULE uwsgi;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_CALLABLE application;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/aristatek/britishQueue/uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

uwsgi.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from britishQueue import webserve as application # why so picky all the time..

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=6002, debug=True)
```

which one is supposed to properly help me start the server under uwsgi's control?

I've created a git branch with only the more relevant code if needed (and there's always the master branch): https://github.com/Thetoxicarcade/britishQueue/tree/flaskBug

edit (using production's log file):

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.12 (64bit) on [Tue Jan 19 14:40:02 2016] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.4 on 13 January 2016 14:22:40
os: Linux-3.16.0-57-generic #77~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 23:20:00 UTC 2015
nodename: intern.alpha.aristatek.com
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 8
current working directory: /home/aristatek/britishQueue/flask
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 31835
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /home/aristatek/britishQueue/flask/uwsgi.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:01:27)  [GCC 4.8.2]
Set PythonHome to /home/aristatek/britishQueue/clearable
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1ab2c80
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 415360 bytes (405 KB) for 8 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x1ab2c80 pid: 1148 (default app)
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1148)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 1280, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 1281, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 1283, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 1286, cores: 2)
[pid: 1286|app: 0|req: 1/1] 192.168.2.60 () {54 vars in 1147 bytes} [Tue Jan 19 14:40:14 2016] GET /api/v1.0/status/ => generated 291 bytes in 30 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 84 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 1286|app: 0|req: 2/2] 192.168.2.60 () {54 vars in 1147 bytes} [Tue Jan 19 14:40:15 2016] GET /api/v1.0/status/ => generated 291 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 84 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
[pid: 1286|app: 0|req: 3/3] 192.168.2.60 () {54 vars in 1147 bytes} [Tue Jan 19 14:40:15 2016] GET /api/v1.0/status/ => generated 291 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 84 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

Comment: If you haven't already, I would suggest running uwsgi by itself and verifying that it can correctly serve your application before trying to integrate with nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uwsgi needs to be directly told to use an async-like method. In my case, that's:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins                 = python
virtualenv              = /home/aristatek/britishQueue/clearable
chdir                   = /home/aristatek/britishQueue/flask
module                  = britishQueue
callable                = webserve

uid                     = aristatek
gid                     = aristatek

#http                    = :6002
socket                  = /home/aristatek/britishQueue/flask/uwsgi.sock
chown-socket            = www-data:www-data
chmod-socket            = 666
pidfile2                = /home/aristatek/britishQueue/flask/uwsgi.pid
stats                   = /home/aristatek/britishQueue/flask/uwsgi.stats

#master                  = true
ugreen                  = true
async                   = 4
#workers                 = 4
#enable-threads          = 1
#threads                 = 4
#auto-procname           = 1
#procname-prefix-spaced  = [aristatek_britishQueue]
```

Which works fantastically and lets the threads that fail, fail on their own :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's divide it to steps.

### Built-in HTTP server

First, your application seems to have some built-in http server, let's run it. Just call `python wsgi.py` and on address `127.0.0.1:6002` will be your application (if you're doing it on remote server, replace 127.0.0.1 with his IP address).

This will help you narrow errors in application.

If this works fine, stop that application server (probably ctrl+c or ctrl+d).

### uWSGI server

Now, when you're sure that app is working, let's try to put it behind uWSGI. Here is configuration that works for me every time:

```
chdir                   = /home/aristatek/britishQueue # put here directory, where you're storing your app code
uid                     = aristatek # username and groupname on which your app will be running (if you're running uWSGI as root, you really should do this, for security reasons)
gid                     = aristatek
auto-procname           = 1 # this 2 options will set user-readable name for your uWSGI processes, in this example each processname will be prefixed by your username and app name
procname-prefix-spaced  = [aristatek_britishQueue]

#chmod-socket            = 660 # this 2 options will ensure that your socket will be readable by user that is running app and uWSGI, no one else.
#chown-socket            = aristatek:www-data
#socket                  = /home/aristatek/britishQueue/uwsgi.sock
http                    = :8000
pidfile2                = /home/aristatek/britishQueue/uwsgi.pid

virtualenv              = /home/aristatek/britishQueue/clearable
workers                 = 4
threads                 = 2
master                  = true
module                  = wsgi # python path to your wsgi file, relative to main project dir
enable-threads          = 1

logger                  = file:/home/aristatek/britishQueue/uWSGI.log
```

After running that uWSGI server, go to `127.0.0.1:8000` in your browser. That should give your same results as running application built-in server. If not, check uWSGI logs (located in your project dir by default) for clue why it isn't working.

If uWSGI is working fine, uncomment in it's config lines with `socket` and comment `http one` (or remove).

### nginx server

Here is my config for nginx to communicate with uWSGI app:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name intern.alpha.aristatek.com default_server;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    root /home/aristatek/britishQueue/srv/;

    location @britishQueue {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;

        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/aristatek/britishQueue/uwsgi.sock;
        break;
    }

    location /api/ {
        try_files $uri @default;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        try_files /500.html /error.html /error500.html;
    }
}
```

And that's it, your app should be accessible on address `intern.alpha.aristatek.com`. If it's not, check nginx errors and if nginx is running on `www-data` user and group and if not, change groupname for uwsgi socket in your uWSGI config file.

Comment: Just got back. `python uwsgi.py` works fine, but running the uwsgi -i uwsgi process is slow and can only run using `module = britishQueue; callable = webserve`, and further beyond that nginx wasn't loading it, so I tried to use daemonize which doesn't work any more ('connect(): Permission denied [core/loggin.c line 276]'... But your advice is incredibly helpful and I thank you for that.

Comment: That means there is something wrong with wsgi part of your application. On what libraries is based on?

Comment: uwsgi --version gives 2.0.12, pip show uwsgi gives: Metadata-Version: 1.0
Name: uWSGI
Version: 2.0.12
Summary: The uWSGI server
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author: Unbit
Author-email: info@unbit.it
License: GPL2
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: (long error message)

Comment: I'm not asking about uWSGI but about your application that you're trying to run on top of uWSGI.

Comment: it seems to be that I goofed on the http port the application was running on, possibly, and that I can't call celery's .delay() method within uwsgi. Thank You for all your help :)